# Jacoco code coverage report showing wrong

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

When I run individual test classes, it shows 100% coverage where as when I taken maven build for whole project then Jacoco report showing wrong coverage percentage for many classes. Is there a way to get jacaco report per test class?

Below is my pom configuration

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Do you have a reproducer for the wrong coverage score? 
Here are solutions to get per test coverage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094676/jacoco-coverage-per-test-setup

Comment: Hi David, When i right click my test file on Intellij and do run With Coverage, its showing 100% coverage. But When i run maven install which also runs all tests in my project and create jacaco report, i see coverage for same file as 6% . I dont understand why because logically i have written many test cases including positive and negative for the class and im sure it covers all the lines of my class. i m using Jacaco as shown in my pom.xml in post

Comment: I also checked the link you shared before, i wasnt able to run my tests when i was using sure-fire plugin as suggested in post. I followed exact same steps mentioned there. so reverted them back

Comment: Normally in the Jacoco report you see every line and branch that has coverage. Look in target/site/jacoco/

Comment: HI David, yes i checked same, its showing most of the lines in red, though i have unit tests that execute those lines. Same files is shown full green on all lines when i run test class with intellj run with coverage option.

Comment: What i feel happening is when i run individual test class, its coverage is shown correctly, where as when i run all tests at once, coverage is overwritten in the order of test classes executed. For example I have a CustomException class with a test class, when i run it individually it shows 100% coverage on CustomException class. But when i run all tests , lets say the last test class that is getting executed has used only 1 method in my CustomException then the previously reported 100% coverage by CustomExceptionTest class is replaced with 50% by last executed TestClass.

Comment: Any idea how i can generate cumulative report without data getting overwritten? The report i see finally is the coverage of last test class that got executed in sequence.

Comment: To be honst i have no idea and never encountered this. Maybe you should try to get  sure-fire running i never saw jacoco running without it and didnt even know it was possible

Comment: hi, mine was multi module project. i followed exact steps mentioned in below link and it solved my problem.                                                                                                              https://giri-tech.blogspot.com/2021/08/maven-multi-module-java-project-code.html?lr=1

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps in below link and it solved the issue. Note, mine was a multi module project and i wanted code coverage as a single report for all modules.

https://giri-tech.blogspot.com/2021/08/maven-multi-module-java-project-code.html